# Installation of PRANK MSA in WLS Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sequence-alignment

I want to install [PRANK](http://wasabiapp.org/software/prank/prank_installation/) on the Windows 10 Linux subsystem (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), I have followed the installation instructions to no avail.

```
wget http://wasabiapp.org/download/prank/prank.source.140603.tgz
tar xvzf prank.source.140603.tgz
cd prank-msa/src
make
./prank

[ cp prank ~/bin ]
[ sudo cp prank /usr/bin ]
```

I followed those instructions but got stuck with `cd prank-msa/src` I don't know why they want me to enter a directory that doesn't exist. I also followed this video on how to install linux files but it wasn't helpful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their instructions are outdated and don't match what exists on their server. The problem you're running into is not at the `cd` step but even before that - at your first step even. Your `wget` fails because that file does not exist. Go to http://wasabiapp.org/download/ and see for yourself - there is no `/prank/` directory in there.

I tried using `curl`, and it wrote the 404 page as a `.tar.gz` file, so if you did that, the tar step would error out.